# ImportXML in GoogleSheets sporadically returns "Imported content is empty"

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, xpath, import, google-sheets-formula

We've created a web scraper to Amazon that uses the ImportXML function in Google Sheets.
The formula is repeated multiple times per web page to scrape all the data needed.

Lately we've noticed a bizarre behavior - some of the cells will work one day, the next they are returning an "Imported content is empty" error and then the following day they are working again.

Weirder still, if we wait enough time without doing a thing, a cell with an error can fix itself and populate.

We tried creating a copy of the file and the result was that the error appeared in different cells than the original and the cells that were working in the original had the error in the copy file.

All the formulas are similar for all the cells, with concatenation to allow for different web pages.

Is there anything to do other than waiting enough time for the cells to work themselves out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely you have too many `IMPORTXML` formulae in your sheet. there is a limit 50-200 imports per spreadsheet. try to optimize your sheet or use different method to get the data (API calls via scripts)